# Load Keystore from Beanshell in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, keystore, beanshell

I'm trying to load a Keystore with multiple certificates from a Beanshell.
Here is my code :

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager;
setStrictJava(true);

String COMMON_PATH = vars.get("COMMON_PATH");
String KEY = "******";
String PATH = COMMON_PATH + "/keystore.jks";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",PATH);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",KEY);
System.setProperty("https.use.cached.ssl.context","false");
SSLManager.getInstance().reset();
```

This code works but it only loads the first certificate of the Keystore .. which annoys me. How can I load the Keystore with every certificate?

Damien

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of dealing with multiple SSL certificates residing in the keystore is using [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) element like it's described in the [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article.

Also be aware that you can put your keystore path and password to the *system.properties* file so you won't have to go for scripting.

If you for any reason want to do this programmatically consider switching to [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)